# Sink Level, Top of Drain Level, Bottom of Drain Not Level, Causing Leak

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

The bottom of the drain hole on the new sink I just installed is cut/shaped at an angle so that it isn't level with the rest of the sink. So when I tighten the collar below the cone gasket tight with the bottom of the sink, it pushes the tail pipe to that same angle, which means the gasket on the top of the drain is no longer flush and allows water to leak out on one side.

All the advice I can find by googling is based around a new/different drain which doesn't seem like it will help considering it's the bottom of the sink that's causing the problem. Suggestions?

[image: Bottom of sink and gasket]

[image: Top of sink drain]

Comment: There is another question on here that mentions sanding, grinding, and using putty type products, but with a new sink would just return it for being defective.  Check replacements for same defect before accepting.

Comment: Yeah, I think in my heart I know that's the solution, I'm just trying to avoid my entire morning wasted getting this vanity top installed. It's hard to know how I would test for the same defect in the store (I guess take a level?). Would it be worth trying plumber's putty on the top to fill the gap before I take the sink back out?

Comment: The putty might stop leak, but won't prevent the tilt.  Can try phoning the store/manufacturer and see if there is any thing to add/do/missing.

Comment: Leaving as A comment because if the sink drain assembly won’t seal with a bead of plumbers putty it needs to be returned!!!! But if the assembly seals and I have had this with undercounter granite and a corian?  Then you need to adapt the trap to this angle. In that case a left to right pitch is no big deal when connecting to the horizontal pipe in a wall but some “wonky” angle other than that can be fixed with pvc plumbing with a commercial heat gun or for most DIY’s a propane torch. The torch or heat gun can soften plastic pipe and correct the misalignment.

Comment: I'm not adding this an answer since I don't feel strongly that it's "correct" but I ended up just putting a bead of silicone caulk around the drain to stop the leak for the time being and work on it more later. As of a month later, it seems to be holding up.

Answer (score 0):

For weird angles I use a fitting like this:

[image]

It's basically a flexible PVC pipe that can be glued to standard rigid PVC pipe using standard PVC glue. It saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: While useful and useable, they tend to clog quickly in a bathroom sink (hairs love to settle in all those accordion pleats). Also, There's no good reason for a brand new sink to need this to overcome a manufacturing defect. Only use something like this when there's no option to twist the P-trap into the right position to get plumbing to line up.